# Why joblib is not recommended when saving keras model?

Tags: python, keras, pickle, joblib

According to [this](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) keras documentation, pickle is not recommended to save keras mode, and since `joblib.dump()` and `joblib.load()` are based on the Python pickle serialization model, joblib is also not recommended to save keras model. What is the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to save my keras model as `'.pkl'` using `joblib.dump()`, but when I try to make a prediction for an unseen parameter after loading it using `joblib.load()` I get an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'.`

It is recommended to use `model.save('model.h5')`

As an alternative to speed up the loading, it is better to store the structure of networks and weight in two different files:

**Saving:**

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

model.save_weights('model.h5')
model_json = model.to_json()
with open('model.json', "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
json_file.close()
```

**Loading:**

```
json_file = open("model.json", 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model.load_weights("model.h5")
```